# Button object not callable in the tkinter code

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import * 
root=Tk()
#  not required here root.geometry()
root.title("calculator")
entry=Entry(root,width=50,borderwidth=5)
entry.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,padx=10,pady=10)
def button_add(number): 
    entry.insert(0,number)
def clear(): 
    entry.delete(0,END)
button_1=Button(root,text="1",padx=40,pady=20,command=lambda: button_add(1))
button_2=Button(root,text="2",padx=40,pady=20,command=lambda: button_add(2))
button_3=Button(root,text="3",padx=40,pady=20,command=lambda: button_add(3))
button_4=Button(root,text="4",padx=40,pady=20,command=lambda: button_add(4))
button_5=Button(root,text="5",padx=40,pady=20,command=lambda: button_add(5))
button_6=Button(root,text="6",padx=40,pady=20,command=lambda: button_add(6))
button_7=Button(root,text="7",padx=40,pady=20,command=lambda: button_add(7))
button_8=Button(root,text="8",padx=40,pady=20,command=lambda: button_add(8))
button_9=Button(root,text="9",padx=40,pady=20,command=lambda: button_add(9))
button_0=Button(root,text="0",padx=40,pady=20,command=lambda: button_add(0))
button_add=Button(root,text='+',padx=39,pady=20)
button_equal=Button(root,text='=',padx=95,pady=20)
def clear(): 
    entry.delete(0,END)
button_clear=Button(root,text='clear',padx=141.5,pady=10,command=clear)
# grid being set 
button_1.grid(row=1,column=0)
button_2.grid(row=1,column=1)
button_3.grid(row=1,column=2)
button_4.grid(row=2,column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2,column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2,column=2)
button_7.grid(row=3,column=0)
button_8.grid(row=3,column=1)
button_9.grid(row=3,column=2)
button_add.grid(row=4,column=0)
button_equal.grid(row=4,column=1,columnspan=2)
button_clear.grid(row=5, column=0,columnspan=4)

root.mainloop()
```

This is my tkinter code , i was creating a calculator in Python and I came across this error, if I clicked on any button

> button_8=Button(root,text="8",padx=40,pady=20,command=lambda:
> button_add(8)) TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable

Please someone help how should I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a closer look and you will notice that your function and add button variable have the same name, and hence python is confused which one to call, so just change, either the function name or the button name.

```
add_button = Button(root,text='+',padx=39,pady=20)
add_button.grid(row=4,column=0)
```

Also, I know the code is still incomplete but just keep this in mind, each time you click on the number button, the number will be shown towards the starting of the entry widget, to get rid of this, say:

```
def button_add(number): 
    entry.insert(END,number) #END will always add the number to the end, rather than 0th postion like before
```

Im telling this now, because I think the next step your going to do to avoid this is:

```
def button_add(number):
    e = entry.get()
    entry.delete(0,END)
    entry.insert(0,e+str(number))
```

This is not necessary at all since you have a built in `END` variable with tkinter.