# I'm getting this error in tkinter: TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, typeerror, calculator

I'm working on a GUI for my calculator but I ran into an error.
In the last few questions, I posted on my GUI project, I received really useful answers. So I'd like to thank everyone who helped me.
This time, however, I ran into a different error.
I've seen a couple of similar questions and the closest to my problem was this one... [Button object not callable in the tkinter code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548607/button-object-not-callable-in-the-tkinter-code)
I tried the solution given, but it threw me the same error. I apologize if this question is a duplicate of another question on SO.

**Error**
`TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable`
I get this error when I click on the clear button in my GUI.

**This is my code...**

```
                                 import tkinter as Tk
                                 from tkinter import *
                                 root_var = Tk()
                                 root_var.title("Calculator")

                                 e = Entry(root_var, width=25, borderwidth=5)
                                 e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

                                 def button_click(number=None):

                                 #e.delete(0, END)
                                 current = e.get()
                                 e.delete(0, END)
                                 e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number) )

                                 def button_clear():
                                 e.delete(0, END)

     button_1 = Button(root_var, text="1", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(1))
     button_2 = Button(root_var, text="2", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(2))
     button_3 = Button(root_var, text="3", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(3))
     button_4 = Button(root_var, text="4", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(4))
     button_5 = Button(root_var, text="5", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(5))
     button_6 = Button(root_var, text="6", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(6))
     button_7 = Button(root_var, text="7", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(7))
     button_8 = Button(root_var, text="8", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(8))
     button_9 = Button(root_var, text="9", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(9))
     button_0 = Button(root_var, text="0", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(0))

button_addition = Button(root_var, text="+", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click())
button_subtraction = Button(root_var, text="-", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: 
button_click())
button_multiplication = Button(root_var, text="*", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: 
button_click())
button_division = Button(root_var, text="/", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click())
button_exponents = Button(root_var, text="^", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: 
button_click())

button_equals = Button(root_var, text="=", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click())

button_clear = Button(root_var, text="C", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_clear())

button_1.grid(row=3, column=2)
button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3, column=0)

button_4.grid(row=2, column=2)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=0)

button_7.grid(row=1, column=2)
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1, column=0)

button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)
button_addition.grid(row=4, column=1)
button_subtraction.grid(row=4, column=2)

button_multiplication.grid(row=5, column=0)
button_division.grid(row=5, column=1)
button_exponents.grid(row=5, column=2)

button_equals.grid(row=6, column=0)
button_clear.grid(row=6, column=1)
root_var.mainloop()
```

Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Why does your button have the same name as one of your functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

same function name and variable name there for your program isn't working

```
#corrected
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import *
root_var = Tk()
root_var.title("Calculator")

e = Entry(root_var, width=25, borderwidth=5)
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

def button_click(number=None):

 #e.delete(0, END)
    current = e.get()
    e.delete(0, END)
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number) )

def clear():
    e.delete(0, END)

button_1 = Button(root_var, text="1", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(root_var, text="2", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(root_var, text="3", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(root_var, text="4", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(root_var, text="5", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(root_var, text="6", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(root_var, text="7", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(root_var, text="8", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(root_var, text="9", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(9))
button_0 = Button(root_var, text="0", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click(0))

button_addition = Button(root_var, text="+", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click())
button_subtraction = Button(root_var, text="-", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: 
button_click())
button_multiplication = Button(root_var, text="*", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: 
button_click())
button_division = Button(root_var, text="/", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click())
button_exponents = Button(root_var, text="^", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: 
button_click())

button_equals = Button(root_var, text="=", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: button_click())

button_clear = Button(root_var, text="C", padx=50, pady=10, command=lambda: clear())

button_1.grid(row=3, column=2)
button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3, column=0)

button_4.grid(row=2, column=2)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=0)

button_7.grid(row=1, column=2)
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1, column=0)

button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)
button_addition.grid(row=4, column=1)
button_subtraction.grid(row=4, column=2)

button_multiplication.grid(row=5, column=0)
button_division.grid(row=5, column=1)
button_exponents.grid(row=5, column=2)

button_equals.grid(row=6, column=0)
button_clear.grid(row=6, column=1)
root_var.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would still be a good idea to change `command=lambda: clear()` to just `command=clear`. That way you aren't creating a new `lambda` object in memory.