# TypeError: 'Button' object is not callable

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

I am facing issue while coding this simple calculator. lambda function works fine for number but not the clear option. Can anyone explain what is happening here?

```
def button_click(number):
   current = e.get() #fetch the number
   e.delete(0, END) #removes the botton and just tags the most recent number to insert
   e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number)) #insert the number 

def button_clear():
    e.delete(0, END)

button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx =35, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))

button_clear = Button(root, text="Clear", padx=25, pady=20, command=lambda: button_clear())
```

Note that the above code works fine without a lambda function inside the clear button grid.

Comment: You have reassigned the `button_clear` variable with a `Button` on the last line. Use a different name. Eg. `button_2`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Button object not callable in the tkinter code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548607/button-object-not-callable-in-the-tkinter-code)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is simple.

In your code, there is a function named `button_clear()` and a button named the same ( `button_clear` ).

So when you're trying to call the `button_clear()` function, the system understands that you're trying to call the `button_clear` button and raise an error.

All you need to do is to change the function's name.

```
def function():
    #your code
```

#### So the code should be:

```
def button_click(number):
   current = e.get() #fetch the number
   e.delete(0, END) #removes the botton and just tags the most recent number to insert
   e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number)) #insert the number

def function():
    e.delete(END, 0)

button_1 = Button(root, text="1", padx =35, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))

button_clear = Button(root, text="Clear", padx=25, pady=20, command=lambda: function())
```

This full answer might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548629/17990633

Have a good day!